# Update detached objects causes violation primary key exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Although violation PRIMARY KEY constraint is answered several time, non of them couldn't solve my problem. Consider below model. Each `Course` object can have several resources and each `CourseResource` can belong to several courses.

```
public class Course 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // other properties
    public IList<CourseResourse> CourseResources {get; set;}
}

public class CourseResouce 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // other properties
    public IList<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}
```

The edit action for `Course` model are:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        Course course = db.Courses
            .Include(x => x.CourseResources)
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (course == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        db.Detach(course.CourseResources);

        CourseVm courseVm = new CourseVm()
        {
            Course = course,
            // other properties
        };

        return View(courseVm);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CourseVm courseVm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        IList<int> rsIds = courseVm.Course.CourseResources.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

        Course c = db.Courses.Find(courseVm.Course.Id);
        if (c.IsNotNull())
        {
            db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var resourceId in rsIds)
            {
                var rs = db.CourseResources.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == resourceId);
                if (rs.IsNotNull())
                    c.CourseResources.Add(rs);
            }

            db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();  // <- Error here
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Description:

1. I tried to detach the child objects (`CourseResources`) from `course`
2. Clear the resources from received `Course` (ViewModel)
3. Save course
4. Then add new `CourseResourse`s to it
5. When I try to save an exception will be raised

   > Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.CourseTypeCourses'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CourseTypeCourses'.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is CourseTypeCourses? and is there any chance that rsIds has duplicates?

Comment: @roozbehS no way, there is no duplicates.

Comment: I think the problem is the relation between `Course` and `CourseResource` is not cleared

Comment: It seems that another property named CourseType is the problem. Can you provide it's code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must assume that the "dbo.CourseTypeCourses" is the intermediate table that holds both keys of Cources and CourceResources, and that you indeed try to add a record that already exists.

Note that the detach action you do on the CourceResources in the GET method, does not pass the end of that method, because you don't save any changes on your db object (and frankly you shouldn't go this way at all). So when you get your database objects in your POST method, you get them as they were in the beginning.

To explain this more, note that the Controller class implements the IDisposable interface, disposing the instanse on the end of each call and running the default constructor on the beginning of each call. So any changes on the properties of your controller (i.e. the db object) does not pass the end of the call. Your db object is being initiallized on every call, along with the controller.

The way to proceed with what you want to do is in my opinion a lot simpler:

- You don't need to make any changes on you db objects in the GET method.
- In your POST method get the Course from the db (as you do), *including* the CourseResources. Clear all items from the CourseResources and add all the new ones (as you do)

So try something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    Course course = db.Courses
        .Include(x => x.CourseResources)
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (course == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    //db.Detach(course.CourseResources);

    CourseVm courseVm = new CourseVm()
    {
        Course = course,
        // other properties
    };

    return View(courseVm);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CourseVm courseVm)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       IList<int> rsIds = courseVm.Course.CourseResources.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    Course c = db.Courses
        .Include(x => x.CourseResources)
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (c.IsNotNull())
    {
        c.CourseResources.Clear();

        foreach (var resourceId in rsIds)
        {
            var rs = db.CourseResources.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == resourceId);
            if (rs.IsNotNull())
                c.CourseResources.Add(rs);
        }

        db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Merry coding!